# Changing value from a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just trying to change the value from a nested dictionary.

The first dictionary is empty and the second one is populated.
When I'm trying to change the value of one of the item in the nested dictionary, also the value with the same key of the others items has been changed.

```
name = dict()
work = {"hour" : 4, "age":21}

name['bob'] = work
name['harry'] = work

name['bob']['hour'] = 7
```

Now I obtain this if i print the new *name* dictionary:

```
{'bob': {'hour': 7, 'age': 21}, 'harry': {'hour': 7, 'age': 21}}
```

I'd like to have this situation:

```
{'bob': {'hour': 7, 'age': 21}, 'harry': {'hour': 4, 'age': 21}}
```

Why does it change the hour from the dictionary of *harry*?

Comment: Use ``name['bob'] = work.copy()`` and ``name['harry'] = work.copy()``.It will pass the reference not the value.

Comment: They are both references to the same value. You're going to want to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both names refer to the same element, i.e. references to the same value. You should copy the `dict` instead of simple assignment like the following:

```
name = dict()
work = {"hour" : 4, "age":21}

name['bob'] = work.copy()
name['harry'] = work.copy()

name['bob']['hour'] = 7
```

Comment: you don't need to import `copy` for shallow copy

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you assign the same object that you defined before.

Try to use dict copy:

```
name = dict()
work = {"hour" : 4, "age":21}

name['bob'] = work.copy()
name['harry'] = work.copy()

name['bob']['hour'] = 7
```

If `work` was nested dictionary, you would have to use `deepcopy` (`copy` creates shallow copy which doesn't copy nested structures):

```
from copy import deepcopy
name['bob'] = deepcopy(work)
name['harry'] = deepcopy(work)
```